# Cannot use context.Context as gob RPC call parameter in golang

Tags: go, rpc, gob

I try to write a kv-raft server code in Go. (refer this [article](http://otm.github.io/2015/05/raft-a-first-implementation/)).

However I found there is problem if I want using `context.Context` in my RPC call parameter

```
// Init of my RPC server
kv := new(KVRaft)
rpcs := rpc.NewServer()
rpcs.Register(kv)
....


//My RPC call function
func (kv *KVRaft) Msg(args *context.Context, reply *MsgReply) error {
    log.Println("[MSG]", *args)
    return nil
}
```

Code could be compiled but when I trying to run

```
c, _ := rpc.Dial("tcp", ":1234")
var reply MsgReply{}

c.Call("KVRaft.Msg", someContext, &reply)
```

It will pop-up error as  `gob: type not registered for interface: context.emptyCtx`

This code works well if I replace `*context.Context` to `*string`.
I googled it could use `gob.Register()`, but I got compile failed on `gob.Register(context.Context{})`

```
invalid type for composite literal: "golang.org/x/net/context".Context
```

Any idea how could I pass `context.Context` as gob RPC call parameter?

[update]

I try to use `gob.Register(context.Background())` but it will get empty context  when receive  RPC call.

[update]
Currently my [repo](https://github.com/kkdai/rs) here, but still ongoing.

Comment: `context.Context` is an interface, not a struct. You don't need to register an interface for gob to encode it. You should register the type(s) you're putting inside your context and encode those, putting them into a *new* context on the remote end.

Comment: @elithrar Thanks, I try to use gob.Encode but it still got error on `gob: type not registered for interface: context.emptyCtx`. Any more direction how I trying to find a way to encode it?

Comment: Hi @EvanLin! Did you get any explanation ever since? Thx

Comment: @elithrar could you provide a few lines to illustrate?